# which package replaced the libzimg-dev?

Tags: 18.04

there is no libzimg-dev anymore, I guess the name is somehow changed, which package contain this?
It was there in 16.04.

Comment: No package by that name was (or is) in Ubuntu 16.04 repositories. Clearly you got it from *somewhere*, just not from us. Look at your Non-Ubuntu sources.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, as the launchpad still lists it as a valid package (even though it seems to have not been updated since early 2018 according to the changelog), you can follow this link and download the .deb file yourself if that helps: https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/bionic-media/+sourcepub/9055776/+listing-archive-extra

Edit 2: For this package, you'll need to run the following two commands to add the PPA to get the package through apt-get:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/bionic-media
sudo apt-get update
```

Then Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libzimg-dev
```

Edit: That download link should be for 18.04, just make sure you properly get the 64 bit version if you have a 64 bit install of Ubuntu or 32bit for 32 bit Ubuntu.

Hope this helps you out! :)

Comment: Thanks! Since it is quite old now. I will just build it from source. But anyone donnot want to build should try with this guide.